# Как формировать ленту подписок, чтобы не положить БД?

Tags: android, python, база-данных, веб-программирование, django

Есть приложение, соцсеть где люди публикуют видео и могут подписываться друг на друга.

Так вот вопрос в том, как мне нужно формировать ленту подписок для пользователя ( у которого допустим 200 подписок),как нужно проверять наличие новых публикаций у тех людей на кого я подписан? Как нужно это делать что-бы не положить бд?

Чтобы стало понятней что мне именно нужно приведу схему работы которую я придумал сейчас (но она как по мне слишком является слишком трудной для выполнения сервером. На ошибки этой схемы не обращайте внимания,я её просто привел для понимания того что нужно):

**Пользователь заходит в приложение и при открытии окна подписок отсылаеться запрос на сервер. На сервере в БД смотрится список людей на которых подписан данный пользователь, следом я беру каждого человека из этого списка и обращаюсь к его табличке в БД, там смотрю наличие пометки о том не появилась ли новая публикация,и если эта пометка есть то отдаю эту публикацию в ленту подписок пользователя.**

З.ы Примером того что нужно реализовать является лента подписок из Инстаграма.

Comment: Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону таких хранилищ как Redis, например?

Comment: Было бы удобней, если бы Вы предоставили структуру базы

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется в первую очередь стоит сделать пагинацию, чтобы сервер на один запрос отдавал какое-то кол-во информации, а не все сразу, например по 10 записей для каждого пользователя. Я бы, скорее всего, отталкивался не от "новой" публикации, а от времени всех публикаций. Взять всех подписчиков пользователя -> Взять все записи для всех подписчиков подписчиков пользователя за последний час -> Отдать все записи в хроннологическом порядке. Или отдать частями по страницам `page1` - самое свежее и далее `pageN` более ранние записи. `Django` умеет пагинацию, у меня прекрасно получалось с подобной задачей. Возможно есть решение лучше, Ваш вопрос по архитектуре приложения, а это совсем не простая штука.